# Is it possible to have ehcache configuration driven by application.properties file in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, ehcache

I am trying to use ehcache for second level hibernate cache but since the properties should be defined in xml file, how can i do it using application.properties file?

here is my xml file:
`

```
  <defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="100"
        timeToIdleSeconds="20000"
        timeToLiveSeconds="3"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        diskPersistent="false"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
 />
</ehcache>`
```

I tried using placeholder, but turns out is not supported here.

Comment: You cannot, unless you add properties and add a java based configuration to configure EhCache.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you please share any resource where this type of configuration is used?

Comment: No I cannot as that isn't standard for Sprig boot and requires custom configuration classes. Basically you would need to add properties which you read and use that to configure JCache with Java. Both are explained in their respective documentation.